# How to load locally build assemblies for debugging purposes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, sharpdx

I need to debug SharpDX to understand what is going on in my app - my project uses it via a reference from another NuGet package. Since the first package is referencing it with a PublicKeyToken even though I have built the same version of SharpDX and switched the SharpDX reference from NuGet to the local assemblies, my project wont build since it seems that it wants a signed version of SharpDX. The error message I am getting during the build is:

> Error CS0012: The type 'TextLayout' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'SharpDX.Direct2D1, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1'.

I have built this assembly with the same version (3.1.1.0) but I have not sign it (and I assume I cannot do this since the repo does not contain the key file).

Is there any way around this how I can make the NuGet package that references SharpDX load the locally built assemblies?

I found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/securitytools/2009/12/30/how-to-turn-off-strong-name-validation/) and tried to turn off the strong name validation for that public key token, leave the references in tact (the project still references the SharpDX NuGet package) and replace the binaries and then run the application. It still fails at runtime with:

> Message:Could not load file or assembly 'SharpDX.Direct2D1, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

But this did not match the explicit error about the strong name given in the link. To verify the version I opened the build assembly with ildasm and the version is in tact:

[image]

Comment: According to the error message that you got and the dependencies of SharpDX.Direct2D1 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX.Direct2D1/3.1.1), please make sure you also reference SharpDX and SharpDX.DXGI local build assemblies. And could you tell us which NuGet package that reference SharpDX do you used?